# Using vector field for buffer model in QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I am creating a model that will create a viewshed and a buffer around an observer layer /point. I want to use a field in the observer layer for the buffer range.

I tried the option 'Field type'. But it won't let me select anything. Probably because the system does not know what to select.

Furthermore, I tried a 'Vector Field' as input. And pre-calculated value. The model then generates no matter what a 10m buffer.

How can I create a model where I'm able to select the column name of the buffer range?

EDIT:
Added the graph with the solution.

[image]

[image: Below is the model.]

[image: At the distance field I want a model input]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a field of the attribute table for buffering, you can choose `buffer by variable distance` as the tool you're using, this allows you to write down the field name.

Or when using the plain `buffer` tool as you currently do, you can click data defined override (as you already did in your second screenshot) and then click `edit`. Enter here the field name and confirm.

Comment: Erik, the first solution works.
At the distance field, I selected '@obsserverlayer'. Now it uses the correct radius. But what if I have more than 1 column with integers?

The best case scenario is when a user has the option to choose the radius column.

Comment: Disregard the first comment. 
I got it. 
I used a 'Vector Field' as input. Here the users can select the radius column. This field is the input for the variable distance buffer. 
See 3th screenshot.

Comment: There is no third screenshot @BearHunt

Comment: I was still editing. 
Now there is a third screenshot